# complexity - bigtheta 3 for cycle

Tags: for-loop, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

I just resolve a problem but i don't have the solution of that so i kindly ask you if you can confirm if my solution is correct or not

```
int h=1; int cont = 0;

for (j = 2^N; j>1; j = j/2) {
        h = h * 2;
        for (i =1; i < j; i = i*2)
           for (k=2; k<h; k++)
               cont ++;
}
```

I must find the complexity of that portion of code in BIGTHETA.

So, i analyze that the third cycle grow up in that way

k -> linear until = h (h grow up like 2^w) - So the complexity is log n.

About the second, the first cycles' limit is 0 so i think that the complexity is log n.

About the first 2^N = 2^N-1 so the complexity is n

The total complexity is n * log n

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed formally, step by step, using Sigma notation (I skipped some steps, but feel free to ask for more details if necessary):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain me better the step for that solution? The final solution is not 2^N * N^2 ?
Why you did the product of all loop? The 1 and the 2 are dipendent and so i must find the max of that is not correct?

Comment: @user , there is no rule saying that "dependent" loops have a complexity of maximum of each one.